# Reservations (for hotel) upcoming reservations Green , old reservations Red in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've been searching on the web for options like in the title, i've seen an example that the first row is green and the other ones are red, this was the conclusion :

```
<DataGrid>
<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
              Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}}"
              Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

i've tried to change it by editing to a datetime but i'm no expert. I have this

```
 `<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                   <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
```

`

Can somebody help me out?
Thx in advance!

Comment: Probably want to use some sort of converter for this to do the actual logic; then the data triggers on the converter output. Doing the whole thing in XAML just isn't going to end well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use Converters:

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (value.ToString() == "old")
        {
            var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red");
            return color;
        }
        else if (value.ToString() == "Upcoming")
        {
            var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Green");
            return color;
        }


        return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Black");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpf"
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:TestWpf.StringToColorConverter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:StringToColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Binding Path="Reservation" Converter="{StaticResource StringToColorConverter}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XAML below assumes the object it is bound to is `YourItemSource` and it has a property named `Reservation`. If the value of the `Reservation` property is *Old*, it will make the row `Red`. If the value of `Reservation` is *Upcoming*, it will make it `Green`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow"> 
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Reservation}" Value="Old">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Reservation}" Value="Upcoming">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Tweak the names to be inline with your object and property name and values. Also, based on the values indicate what color you want.